# How can I avoid the pyramid of doom with chain in fp-ts?

Tags: typescript, fp-ts

I frequently come up against this situation, where I need to complete several sequential operations. If each operation exclusively used data from the previous step, then I could happily do something like `pipe(startingData, TE.chain(op1), TE.chain(op2), TE.chain(op3), ...)`. I can't find a nice way to write this when `op2` also needs data from `startingData`, without a bunch of nested callbacks.

How can I avoid the pyramid of doom in the example below?

```
declare const op1: (x: {one: string}) => TE.TaskEither<Error, string>;
declare const op2: (x: {one: string, two: string}) => TE.TaskEither<Error, string>;
declare const op3: (x: {one: string, two: string, three: string}) => TE.TaskEither<Error, string>;

pipe(
  TE.of<Error, string>('one'),
  TE.chain((one) =>
    pipe(
      op1({ one }),
      TE.chain((two) =>
        pipe(
          op2({ one, two }),
          TE.chain((three) => op3({ one, two, three }))
        )
      )
    )
  )
);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There *is* a solution to the problem, and it's called "do notation". It's been available in `fp-ts-contrib` for a while, but it now also has a version baked into `fp-ts` itself using the `bind` function (which is defined on all monadic types). The basic idea is similar to what I was doing below - we bind computation results to a particular name, and track those names inside a "context" object as we go along. Here's the code:

```
pipe(
  TE.of<Error, string>('one'),
  TE.bindTo('one'), // start with a simple struct {one: 'one'}
  TE.bind('two', op1), // the payload now contains `one`
  TE.bind('three', op2), // the payload now contains `one` and `two`
  TE.bind('four', op3), // the payload now contains `one` and `two` and `three`
  TE.map(x => x.four)  // we can discharge the payload at any time
)
```

### Original Answer below

I've come up with a solution that I'm not very proud of, but I'm sharing it for possible feedback!

Firstly, define some helper functions:

```
function mapS<I, O>(f: (i: I) => O) {
  return <R extends { [k: string]: I }>(vals: R) =>
    Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(vals).map(([k, v]) => [k, f(v)])) as {
      [k in keyof R]: O;
    };
}
const TEofStruct = <R extends { [k: string]: any }>(x: R) =>
  mapS(TE.of)(x) as { [K in keyof R]: TE.TaskEither<unknown, R[K]> };
```

`mapS` allows me to apply a function to all values in an object (subquestion 1: is there a builtin function that would allow me to do this?). `TEofStruct` uses this function to turn a struct of values into a struct of `TaskEither`s for those values.

My basic idea is to accumulate the new value along with the previous values using `TEofStruct` and `sequenceS`. So far it looks like this:

```
pipe(
  TE.of({
    one: 'one',
  }),
  TE.chain((x) =>
    sequenceTE({
      two: op1(x),
      ...TEofStruct(x),
    })
  ),
  TE.chain((x) =>
    sequenceTE({
      three: op2(x),
      ...TEofStruct(x),
    })
  ),
  TE.chain((x) =>
    sequenceTE({
      four: op3(x),
      ...TEofStruct(x),
    })
  )
);
```

It feels like I could write some kind of helper function that combines `sequenceTE` with `TEofStruct` to reduce the boilerplate here, but I'm still not sure overall if this is the right approach, or if there is a more idiomatic pattern!

Answer (score 0):

Official fp-ts DO notation is here: https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/guides/do-notation.html

But there is nothing wrong with nested logic extraction to its own function.